# How to get Jenkins Environment Variables in scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins

What is the way to get environment variables in a Jenkins scripted pipeline? suppose I have a method in a vars/method.groovy how can I pass the Jenkins environment variables into this method?

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
void call() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From jenkins [doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/#)

```
Jenkinsfile (Scripted Pipeline)
node {
withEnv(['DISABLE_AUTH=true',
         'DB_ENGINE=sqlite']) {
    stage('Build') {
        sh 'printenv'
    }
}
```

}